# Differentiability of a certain piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is rational} \\
-x & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$
It is well-known that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, and discontinuous everywhere else. Now, let's consider the modified function:
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
x^3 & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is rational} \\
-x^3 & \textrm{if } x \textrm{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, $g(x)$ will be again continuous at $x=0$. But I am wondering:

> Is $g(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$?

I think the answer might be 'yes', because by introducing the higher power $x^3$, we have "smoothed out" the behaviour of the function around the origin. On the other hand, the function looks too pathological to admit any points of differentiability.

Comment: Can you compute $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}{g(h)\over h} $?

Comment: Differnciability requires continuity at least in some open interval, otherwise it is impossible. The whole deffinition of a derivative at point $c$ is that the we look at the quaotient dY/dX at some open neighbourhood

Comment: Indeed $\pm x^2$ would have worked as well

Comment: @DavidMitra: I can! Regardless of whether $h$ is rational or irrational, the limit is 0. Wow it is that simple!

Comment: @Belov Your first statement is not true for differentiability at a point, as the example of the OP shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $x\neq 0$ the following holds:

$$\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=\dfrac {g(x)}x=\begin{cases} x^2, &\text{if }x\in \mathbb Q\\
-x^2, &\text{if }x\not \in \mathbb Q\end{cases},$$

therefore $$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}\right)=\underline ?$$
and $g'(0)=\underline ?$.

Comment: Thanks… Now I feel stupid :)

Comment: That is not correct as the limit there tends to 0, but the function still does not have a derivative.

Comment: @Belov What definitions are you using?

Comment: @Belov Of course it has, though only at $x=0$.

Comment: I use the following definition: A derivative is that quotient of a function at point $c$ if the function is continous at some open neighbourhood of $c$
PS: I'll get my analysis old textbook, I might be wrong.

Comment: Well I guess I was wrong you don't need contuninutiy on an open interval, so should be fine.

Comment: @GitGud: What is that `?` with the line below that? Is that line for something here or just it is as `?`. Sorry Git for asking this. :)

Comment: @B.S. I meant to type $\underline \space$ or $?$, but I ended up mixing them and was too lazy to change it ^_^

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to prove that for every real valued function $f$, defined on an non-degenerated open interval containing $0$, which is continuos in $0$, the function $x\cdot f(x)$ is differentiable in $0$.

Comment: Indeed, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{xf(x)-0f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0)$ which exists by continuity of $f$. Thanks for the general fact!

Comment: You're welcome.  It follows that if $f$ is only bounded, that $x^2f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$.